# VBA don't see objects i create outside the loop

Tags: excel, vba

So i got problem with FindNext in my code, its like vba don't see objects i created outside the loop.

```
Sub Macro1()

'Dwa skoroszyty
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Wynik")

Dim NaglowekWiersz, NaglowekKolumna As Integer
NaglowekKolumna = 1
NaglowekWiersz = 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set LpDoZnalezienia = ws1.Range("A:A").Find("lp.", LookAt:=xlPart)
Set RazemDoZnalezienia = ws1.Range("A:A").Find("Razem", LookAt:=xlWhole)

'Petla do szukania pracowników
For a = 1 To 3

If (a > 1) Then
    Set LpDoZnalezienia = ws1.Range("A:A").FindNext(LpDoZnalezienia).Offset(1, 0)
    Set RazemDoZnalezienia = ws1.Range("A:A").FindNext(RazemDoZnalezienia)
End If

'Znalezienie danego pracownika
Set Pracownik = ws1.Range(LpDoZnalezienia, RazemDoZnalezienia).Resize(, 12)
Worksheets("Wynik").Activate

For b = 1 To 35
'Dana Wartość z arkusza wynik aka nagłówek
Dim szukanaWartosc As String
szukanaWartosc = ws2.Cells(1, NaglowekKolumna).Value

'Znaleziona wartosc w arkuszu Sheet1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set WartoscDoZnalezienia = Pracownik.Find(szukanaWartosc, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If WartoscDoZnalezienia Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Line
Else
    Set Znalezione = WartoscDoZnalezienia.Offset(0, 2)
End If
Worksheets("Wynik").Activate
ws2.Cells(NaglowekWiersz + 1, NaglowekKolumna) = Znalezione.Value

Line:
'Przesuniecie naglowka o 1 w arkuszu wynik aby szukalo kolejnej wartości
NaglowekKolumna = NaglowekKolumna + 1
Next b
NaglowekKolumna = a
NaglowekWiersz = NaglowekWiersz + 1
Next a

End Sub
```

When i try to use FindNext with earlier declared Find its giving me Run-time error 91 that Object or variable is not set in this line:

## Error when the code go to findNext

[image: Error when the code go to findNext]

It works perfectly when I copy those 2 line with find next outside the loop. Can somebody tell me what im doing wrong in my code?

Comment: What is `a` when the bug happens? From your description, I would guess that it occurs when `a = 3`. You should check if `LpDoZnalezienia` is `Nothing` before using it. Also, using `Option Explicit` and declaring all of your variables would make your code more robust.

Comment: By a im iterating every employer, the problem is not in the loop, because when i seting loop to do once its working fine, i have problem when it come to 2nd iteration beacuse its like vba don't see that i deaclared find outside of loop, so its crashing when it come to FindNext.

Comment: It hardly matters what you declared outside the loop, because inside the loop you are overwriting the `LpDoZnalezienia` with a new value. Error 91 is caused by `.Offset(1, 0)` when `FindNext` returns `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

`Find()` and `FindNext()` are a little tricky and the documentation is a little confusing.

The `.Find()` used for `.FindNext` is stored in `ws1.Range("A:A")`, and not in `LpDoZnalezienia`. In a nutshell, you need to keep the instance of the `Range` that the find is being operated on, in scope.

So the solution to your problem will be:

```
With ws1.Range("A:A")
    Set LpDoZnalezienia = .Find("lp.", LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not LpDoZnalezienia Is Nothing Then
        For a = 1 To 3
        If (a > 1) Then
            Set LpDoZnalezienia = .FindNext(LpDoZnalezienia).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
End With

With ws1.Range("A:A")
    Set RazemDoZnalezienia = .Find("Razem", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not RazemDoZnalezienia Is Nothing Then
        For a = 1 To 3
        If (a > 1) Then
            Set RazemDoZnalezienia = .FindNext(RazemDoZnalezienia)
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Of note: If you only have 1 or 2 occurrences of "lp." or "Razem" you will get the first Range second time, there is no internal handling to check if `.FindNext()` has already given you a specific `Range`.  You will have to code this yourself..example:

```
With ws.Cells
    Set fr = .Find("value", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not fr Is Nothing Then
        frAddress = fr.Address
        Do
            Set fr = .FindNext(After:=fr)
            'Do something with found range here.
             Debug.print fr.Address
        Loop While frAddress <> fr.Address
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Worth noting that unless you're changing the found values then you don't need to check for `Not fr Is Nothing` in the loop.  `fr` will always be something once it's found the first time as `FindNext` will loop back to the top of the search range - you only need to check for when you get back to the first found address (`frAddress <> fr.Address`)

Comment: I am little confused dont I keep instance of range by declaring it with        
       Set LpDoZnalezienia = 
       ws1.Range("A:A").FindNext(After:=LpDoZnalezienia).Offset(1, 0) ?

Comment: Also how i can make this so it will only use the find in 1st iteration and after this only find next, beacuse it keep giving me same error, and i don't know how to handle it.

Comment: No, the `.Find()` and `FindNext()` both must be in the same `With` block.

Comment: You may be able to save the searched range `(ws1.Range("A:A"))` as a global variable, but of course globals are a sign that there is probably a better way to do something. I've never tried.